# NirSoft Wifi History - Where are those files location in windows os

Tags: windows, security

There is a good software for wi-fi history like below :
[wifi_history_view](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_history_view.html)
I want to know where are those log files in windows os?
Also tell when a hacker come to my pc what logs should i check for his footprints?
Can i delete those logs by range of date using cmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is found inside the link that you gave in your post:

> **Source of Information**
>
> WifiHistoryView loads the Wifi history information from the  `Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational` event log of Windows.
> This event log is usually stored in the following file:
> `C:\windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig%4Operational.evtx`.

You may use the Event Viewer to view this Windows log, and can also use it
for searching and deleting.

To delete an entire log, use the "Clear Log" command in the Event Viewer.
To delete from the command-line, use `wevtutil cl log-name`.

For more information see
[How to clear the Windows Event Log from the command line](https://winaero.com/how-to-clear-the-windows-event-log-from-the-command-line/).